# Pleading guilty for a moving violation from several years ago. Points still apply? NYC

Tags: traffic, new-york-city

I received a ticket for a moving violation back in 2015, in Brooklyn, NY, and recruited a local law firm to help me fight this traffic ticket.

The firm's strategy was to keep postponing the hearing until the officer who issued this ticket would not show up, making the case dismissed.

Several days ago I received a call from the law office saying that the hearing had actually happened this year, and that I have been found guilty.

They also claimed that points for this violation are now expired because the ticket was issued in 2015.

My questions are:

- How true is their last statement about expiring points?
- Would car
  insurance companies look at expired violations to increase my premium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. [According to New York's DMV](https://dmv.ny.gov/tickets/about-nys-driver-point-system), points only expire when the conviction comes off your record, however for license suspension purposes, they will only look at the last 18 months. You'll have to ask your insurance company how they use points for changing premiums.